# scikit-learn classification on soft labels

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

According to the documentation it is possible to specify different loss functions to `SGDClassifier`. And as far as I understand `log loss` is a `cross-entropy` loss function which theoretically can handle soft labels, i.e. labels given as some probabilities [0,1].

The question is: is it possible to use `SGDClassifier` with `log loss` function out the box for classification problems with soft labels? And if not - how this task (linear classification on soft labels) can be solved using scikit-learn?

**UPDATE:**

The way `target` is labeled and by the nature of the problem hard labels don't give good results. But it is still a classification problem (not regression) and I wan't to keep probabilistic interpretation of the `prediction` so regression doesn't work out of the box too. Cross-entropy loss function can handle soft labels in `target` naturally. It seems that all loss functions for linear classifiers in scikit-learn can only handle hard labels.

So the question is probably:

How to specify my own loss function for `SGDClassifier`, for example. It seems `scikit-learn` doesn't stick to the modular approach here and changes need to be done somewhere inside it's sources

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/arima-for-classification-with-soft-labels-29f3109d9840

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to the docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html),

> The ‘log’ loss gives logistic regression, a probabilistic classifier.

In general a loss function is of the form `Loss( prediction, target )`, where `prediction` is the model's output, and `target` is the ground-truth value. In the case of logistic regression, `prediction` is a value on `(0,1)` (i.e., a "soft label"), while `target` is `0` or `1` (i.e., a "hard label").

So in answer to your question, it depends on if you are referring to the `prediction` or `target`. Generally speaking, the form of the labels ("hard" or "soft") is given by the algorithm chosen for `prediction` and by the data on hand for `target`.

If your data has "hard" labels, and you desire a "soft" label output by your model (which can be thresholded to give a "hard" label), then yes, logistic regression is in this category.

If your data has "soft" labels, then you would have to choose a threshold to convert them to "hard" labels before using typical classification methods (i.e., logistic regression). Otherwise, you could use a regression method where the model is fit to predict the "soft" target. In this latter approach, your model could give values outside of `(0,1)`, and this would have to be handled.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm referring to `target`. The way it's labeled and by the nature of the problem hard labels don't give good results. But it is still a classification problem (not regression) and I wan't to keep probabilistic interpretation of the `prediction` so regression doesn't work out of the box too. Cross-entropy loss function can handle soft labels in `target` naturally

Comment: So no, `SGDClassifier` will not, as far as I am aware, handle your situation unless you threshold your target labels first. Your other option is to, like I said above, create a regression model using `sklearn` using standard regression techniques (and squash the prediction to [0,1] after) or roll-your-own model, using Theano, for example, where the loss could be cross-entropy between continuous-valued prediction on [0,1] and continuous-valued target on [0,1].

Comment: Yes, probably the latter would be a better approach for me

Answer (score 13):

I recently had this problem and came up with a nice fix that seems to work.

Basically, transform your targets to log-odds-ratio space using the inverse sigmoid function. Then fit a linear regression. Then, to do inference, take the sigmoid of the predictions from the linear regression model.

So say we have soft targets/labels `y ∈ (0, 1)` (make sure to clamp the targets to say `[1e-8, 1 - 1e-8]` to avoid instability issues when we take logs).

We take the inverse sigmoid, then we fit a linear regression (assuming predictor variables are in matrix `X`):

```py
y = np.clip(y, 1e-8, 1 - 1e-8)   # numerical stability
inv_sig_y = np.log(y / (1 - y))  # transform to log-odds-ratio space

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X, inv_sig_y)
```

Then to make predictions:

```py
def sigmoid(x):
    ex = np.exp(x)
    return ex / (1 + ex)

preds = sigmoid(lr.predict(X_new))
```

This seems to work, at least for my use case. My guess is that it's not far off what happens behind the scenes for LogisticRegression anyway.

Bonus: this also seems to work with other regression models in `sklearn`, e.g. `RandomForestRegressor`.

Answer (score 1):

for those interested, i've implemented a custom class that behaves like a normal classifier, but takes a any regressor in the cosntructor to perform the transformation suggested by @nlml:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_array
from scipy.special import softmax
import numpy as np

def _log_odds_ratio_scale(X):
    X = np.clip(X, 1e-8, 1 - 1e-8)   # numerical stability
    X = np.log(X / (1 - X))  # transform to log-odds-ratio space
    return X

class FuzzyTargetClassifier(ClassifierMixin, BaseEstimator):
        
    def __init__(self, regressor):
        '''
        Fits regressor in the log odds ratio space (inverse crossentropy) of target variable.
        during transform, rescales back to probability space with softmax function
        
        Parameters
        ---------
        regressor: Sklearn Regressor
            base regressor to fit log odds ratio space. Any valid sklearn regressor can be used here.
        
        '''
        
        self.regressor = regressor
        return
    
    def fit(self, X, y=None, **kwargs):
        #ensure passed y is onehotencoded-like
        y = check_array(y, accept_sparse=True, dtype = 'numeric', ensure_min_features=1)
        self.regressors_ = [clone(self.regressor) for _ in range(y.shape[1])]
        for i in range(y.shape[1]):
            self._fit_single_regressor(self.regressors_[i], X, y[:,i], **kwargs)
        
        return self
    
    def _fit_single_regressor(self, regressor, X, ysub, **kwargs):
        ysub = _log_odds_ratio_scale(ysub)        
        regressor.fit(X, ysub, **kwargs)
        return regressor    
        
    def decision_function(self,X):
        all_results = []
        for reg in self.regressors_:
            results = reg.predict(X)
            if results.ndim < 2:
                results = results.reshape(-1,1)
            all_results.append(results)
        
        results = np.hstack(all_results)                
        return results
    
    def predict_proba(self, X):
        results = self.decision_function(X)
        results = softmax(results, axis = 1)
        return results
    
    def predict(self, X):
        results = self.decision_function(X)
        results = results.argmax(1)
        return results
```